# Is is possible to put a tagged vlan on one physical interface on a Force10 S50N switch?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, lacp

I servers that have a shared ethernet port for IPMI and the first NIC. They have 4-1GbE nics. I would like to bond the nics via LACP while still being able to access the IPMI over a tagged vlan only on the first physical port since the IPMI is only shared on the first physical port. I am also considering buying Force10 S50N switches for my rack. However, I am not sure if this setup can be achieved with FTOS.

FTR, I have managed to achieve this setup with two linux virtual machines. I bonded the ethernet devices on each end. Then I added a vlan to one interface of the bonded links and was able to maintain pings and ssh connections through both networks. The machines were connected physically like so:

```
Mach A     Mach B
eth2<----->eth2
eth3<----->eth3
```

Here are the commands I used to setup the connections:

On Mach A as root:

```
# modprobe bonding mode=4          # mode=4 means 802.3ad or LACP bonding
# ip link add bond0 type bond      # start setting up bonded link
# ip link set eth2 master bond0
# ip link set eth3 master bond0
# ip addr add 192.168.90.1/24 dev bond0
# ip link set bond0 up
# ip link add link eth2.1000 name eth2 type vlan id 1000
# ip addr add 192.168.91.1/24 dev eth2.1000
# ip link set eth2 up
# ip link set eth2.1000 up
```

On Mach B, I just replaced the ip addresses with 192.168.90.2 and 192.168.91.2 for bond0 and eth2.1000 respectively.

I was able to flood ping both simultaneously networks with no packet loss. I was also able to reliable ssh across the machines on both networks while flood pinging.

So, can Force10 switches also be setup this way? If not Force10, are there any switch brands that might work better for me?

Answer (score 1):

On any managed switch you set a physical port with at least one untagged VLAN and as many tagged VLANs you like.

Therefore, if you want VLAN x (the VLAN where you have your LACP) to be available on all ports you set this the default/untagged VLAN for all those ports. And you set VLAN y as tagged on to the physical ports where you can access ipmi.

I don't know about Force10, but this should work with any managed switch which understands 802.1q. I work manly with Alcatel-Lucent OmniSwitch devices, so I use the lingo the Alcatel OS uses